# VSCode debugging in Docker with Mocha and Node

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I have this command that I run for my tests in a docker/mocha/node setup:

```
docker exec -ti dev_chat-app_1 ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha './src/**/*.test.js' --opts './.mocha.opts'
```

This runs the tests, but I want to be able to stop at breakpoints with VScode.

I have this `launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9231,
      "address": "localhost",
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "restart": true
    }
  ]
}
```

And I have this `tasks.json`

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "runMochaInDocker",
      "type": "shell",
      "osx": {
          "command": "docker exec -ti dev_chat-app_1 ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha './src/**/*.test.js' --opts './.mocha.opts'"
      },
      "presentation": {
          "echo": true,
          "reveal": "always",
          "focus": true,
          "panel": "dedicated"
      },
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run `f5` in VScode, the tests are run, but breakpoints are not triggered. I think the task file is working but somethign is wrong with the attach config.

How do I get VScode to work with breakpoints?

Comment: You are setting breakpoint in your vscode, but your code is actually inside docker. That wont work. You need to set breakpoint inside the code that is inside docker container

Comment: Oh I see. vscode allows to develop inside container. Interesting ...
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers